# Does a window need a graphical environment to exist?

Tags: linux, user-interface, window

This one is a pretty strange question of mine so I'll try to explain the best I can.

On a DOS Linux distribution, without having installed any graphical environment, if I start an application which is supposed to have a GUI, will I be able to interact with that window via code?

What I thought is that if KDE/GNOME's role is to graphically represent an existing GUI, I should be able to interact with it but if these graphical environments have an active role in the window creation there is nothing I can do.

Comment: You will have better results using text-only programs. Have you tested this yourself? You can switch to a basic TTY terminal with CTL+ALT+F3 through F6 on Ubuntu and likely many other Linux distributions. If a program is dependent on the X windows system, you can run "startx", but there's a chance that a basic installation won't be configured to run a graphical environment at that point and that X won't crash either. From what I've seen in window manager code, the windows may exist within X and not be directly dependent on the screen being controlled by a window manager.

Comment: What do you mean by a "DOS Linux distribution"? Do you mean a Linux installation without a GUI and only a TTY?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't be able to run a graphical program without a window manager.

The reason is that the window manager is doing a lot more than just allowing the window to be shown to the user. It comes with libraries and services for constructing windows and components and interacting with them. Without these libraries and services, the program won't be able to start.

The only exception would be if a program contained all the graphical code built into it, and didn't rely on a window manager. Realistically this would only happen for a fairly simple program and in special cases; for instance, Raspbian includes OMXPlayer, which shows full screen video without relying on any window manager.

Comment: Is it the window manager supplying libraries or merely an X server or similar window server? My window manager has quite a few functions but most of them mentioning windows just control the screen or internal accounting, it has a very small community so any libraries were probably not used in any other programs, I installed it after all of my graphical programs. Half the imported libraries are from X11 and the rest are for basic system interaction. If X can operate without starting a window manager other programs probably wouldn't know the difference.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting (with some adaptation) from https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/3974 which answers how to start mplayer in X11 without a window manager:

The X server is really usually called `X` and you can just start it. You can set the DISPLAY number as an argument along with some other things.

You might want to have some sort of session, though, and still go through [`xinit`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xinit) or such and start X with [`startx`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/startx). You can use `.xinitrc` or such as a script and simply not start a window manager there. You will need a "magic client" as the last command that stays running so X doesn't terminate immediately. In a traditional "failsafe" session, that was an [`xterm`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xterm). If you know what to launch and launch once only, it could be that program or any UI/wrapper that does the launching for you. When the last ("magic") client in the init script terminates, X terminates.

If all you want to do is play video, you might see if you can run mplayer with [directfb](http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=53&t=16020&p=170011) instead and skip using X11 entirely.